# time shift difference days mysql

Tags: mysql

I can find first-in and last-out with min max at the sameday but at difference day output no change

Table Att

```
  id     tgl                  
| 111 | 2019-02-24 07:30:00  |
| 111 | 2019-02-24 16:31:00  |
| 222 | 2019-02-24 17:59:00  |
| 222 | 2019-02-25 07:31:00  |
| 333 | 2019-02-24 07:30:00  |
| 333 | 2019-02-24 18:00:00  |
```

my query

```
select id, min(date(tgl)) as date_in, max(date(tgl)) as date_out, 
        min(time(tgl)) as jam_in, max(time(tgl)) as jam_out 
from Att 
group by date(tgl),id
```

result my query

```
  id     tgl_in       tgl_out     jam_in    jam_out 
| 111 | 2019-02-24 | 07:30:00 | 2019-02-24 | 16:31:00 |
| 222 | 2019-02-24 | 17:59:00 | 2019-02-24 | 17:59:00 |
| 222 | 2019-02-25 | 07:31:00 | 2019-02-25 | 07:31:00 |
| 333 | 2019-02-24 | 07:30:00 | 2019-02-24 | 18:00:00 |
```

Desired output

```
 id     tgl_in       tgl_out    jam_in    jam_out 
| 111| 2019-02-24 | 2019-02-24 |07:30:00 | 16:31:00 | 
| 222| 2019-02-24 | 2019-02-25 |17:59:00 | 07:31:00 | 
| 333| 2019-02-24 | 2019-02-24 |07:30:00 | 18:00:00 |
```

I change my query to group by id

```
select id, min(date(tgl)) as date_in, max(date(tgl)) as date_out, min(time(tgl)) as jam_in, max(time(tgl)) as jam_out from Att group by id
```

but result time jam_in and jam_out id 222 not correct

```
id  date_in     date_out    jam_in      jam_out
111 2019-02-24  2019-02-24  07:30:00    16:31:00
222 2019-02-24  2019-02-25  07:31:00    17:59:00
333 2019-02-24  2019-02-24  07:30:00    18:00:00
```

Comment: Change `group by date(tgl),id` to  `group by id`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nope. That ain't it.

Comment: Thx @Strawberry, it's affected but only for 2 date, how if more than 2 date?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question, with a corresponding data set and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um,

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,tgl DATETIME
,PRIMARY KEY(id,tgl)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(111,'2019-02-24 07:30:00'),
(111,'2019-02-24 16:31:00'),
(222,'2019-02-24 17:59:00'),
(222,'2019-02-25 07:31:00'),
(333,'2019-02-24 07:30:00'),
(333,'2019-02-24 18:00:00');

SELECT id, MIN(tgl) x, MAX(tgl) y FROM my_table GROUP BY id;
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | x                   | y                   |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| 111 | 2019-02-24 07:30:00 | 2019-02-24 16:31:00 |
| 222 | 2019-02-24 17:59:00 | 2019-02-25 07:31:00 |
| 333 | 2019-02-24 07:30:00 | 2019-02-24 18:00:00 |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The rest of this problem is an exercise in formatting which, while it can be perfectly well dealt with in SQL, is probably best handled in application code.